# Criticizing someone of lower income who buys/lives like someone of higher income?

Tags: word-choice

I have a friend who criticizes people who lives at the place she lives at who make a lower income than her. I thought it would be snob or ignorant, but I feel like those definitions are lacking/vague.

Ex: "This girl who only makes 120K a year does not deserve to be living here. It's almost 1/9th of their income. She should be spending her money on cheaper things"

Comment: A *money snob*?

Comment: Are you looking for a word to describe your friend, or to describe the people she's criticizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say she is an **elitist** in the modern sense of the word.

> A person who believes that they are superior to others (and thus
>   deserve favored status) because of their intellect, social status,
>   wealth, or other factors.

Answer (score 2):

Consider "uppity."

> uppity: *informal* : conspicuously arrogant; condescending.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a technical term but the English phrase is "all fur coat and no knickers"

*edit.* no sexual context - just that everything on show is expensive but there is nothing substantial underneath